# Help with passing ArrayList and parcelable Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable

So I've been googling most of yesterday and last nite and just can't seem to wrap my head around how to pass an arraylist to a subactivity. There are tons of examples and snippets passing **primitive** data types, but what I have is an arraylist of type *address* (address.java below).

I've found a lot of stuff on stackoverflow and around the web on this, but nothing that got a lot of attention except for one with a GeoPoint example.  Again, it looked to me like they just flattened the GeoPoint object into two integers and passed it in.  I can't do that because my address class may expand to include integers, floats, whatever.  Right now, the test app below is only two strings for simplicity.  I thought if I could get the parcelalbe stuff working with that, the rest could follow.

Can someone post a working example for an ArrayList of a non-primitive object, or perhaps add code below to make this work?

**UPDATE**: code below is now working after replies/editing. Thanks!

```
/* helloParcel.java */        
       public class helloParcel extends Activity
{
    // holds objects of type 'address' == name and state
    private ArrayList <address> myList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.main);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(ocl);

        myList = new ArrayList();
        address frank   = new address ("frank", "florida");
        address mary    = new address ("mary", "maryland");
        address monty   = new address ("monty", "montana");

        myList.add (frank);
        myList.add (mary);
        myList.add (monty);

        // add the myList ArrayList() the the extras for the intent

    }

    OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // fill parceable and launch activity
            Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getBaseContext (), subActivity.class);

            // for some reason, I remember a posting saying it's best to create a new
            // object to pass.  I have no idea why..
            ArrayList <address> addyExtras = new ArrayList <address>();

            for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
                addyExtras.add (myList.get(i));

            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra ("mylist", addyExtras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
} 



/* address.java */
  public class address implements Parcelable
{
    private String name;
    private String state;
    private static String TAG = "** address **";

    public address (String n, String s)
    {
        name = n;
        state = s;
        Log.d (TAG, "new address");
    }

    public address (Parcel in)
   {
    Log.d (TAG, "parcel in");
        name = in.readString ();
        state = in.readString ();
   }

    public String getState ()
    {
        Log.d (TAG, "getState()");
        return (state);
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        Log.d (TAG, "getName()");
        return (name);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<address> CREATOR
    = new Parcelable.Creator<address>() 
   {
         public address createFromParcel(Parcel in) 
         {
            Log.d (TAG, "createFromParcel()");
             return new address(in);
         }

         public address[] newArray (int size) 
         {
            Log.d (TAG, "createFromParcel() newArray ");
             return new address[size];
         }
    };

    @Override
   public int describeContents ()
   {
        Log.d (TAG, "describe()");
       return 0;
   }

    @Override
   public void writeToParcel (Parcel dest, int flags)
   {
        Log.d (TAG, "writeToParcel");
       dest.writeString (name);
       dest.writeString (state);
   }

}


/* subActivity.java */
  public class subActivity extends Activity
{
    private final String TAG = "** subActivity **";
    private ArrayList <address> myList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
       Log.d (TAG, "onCreate() in subActivity");

       setContentView(R.layout.subactivity);
       TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_sub);

       myList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra ("mylist");
       Log.d (TAG, "got myList");

       for (int i = 0; i < myList.size (); i++)
       {
        address a = myList.get (i);
        Log.d (TAG, "state:" + a.getState ());
        tv1.setText (a.getName () + " is from " + a.getState ());
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: Greate!!!!!!!!!!!!! Nice Worked , 1st time i used it. Thankssss

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I can see a number of problems here:

1. Why use addressParcelable? Why not make address implement Parcelable, and then use:

   ```
   intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra( "addresses", addyExtras );
   ```
2. Your parcelable object must include a static CREATOR. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for details.
3. You are not actually adding any extras to the intent before you call `startActivity()`. See point 1 for a suggestion here.

I think that you will need to address all of these issues in order to get it working.

Comment: At one point, I thought I needed an extra class (implementing Parcelable) for converting the entire object over.  I think that's where addressParcelable came from.  I've removed it from the code above.  I've implemented your suggestions, albeit probably not properly.  Would you have a look when you get time?  Getting a null pointer error in subActivity() that I'm trying to hunt down now.

Comment: I think that you need to call getIntent().getParcelableArrayList ("mylist"), and not savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList ("mylist");

Comment: do you mean getParcelableArrayListExtra()?  Tried that but getting a new error (see newly edited code above).

Comment: :) I think it's working now! Code edited above - had to modify the constructor in the address class

Comment: Well done in getting it to work. I think you could dispense with addyExtras and just have            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra ("mylist", myList); - which would save you iterating over the list

Answer (score 8):

It can be done MUCH simpler, without all the pain-in-the-ass of implementing `Parcelable`...
`ArrayList` (but NOT any `List`) is `Serializable`. So, you can put the entire list using `putExtra()` and retrieve it using `getSerializableExtra()`, as Sam said.

BUT, I want to add one more important thing: the object your array list stores has to also implement `Serializable`... and all other complex objects that the object may contain (in your case none) must also implement that (so it's recursive - in order to serialize an object, you must be able to serialize all of its fields).

Now, you might be asking yourself why implementing `Serializable` instead of `Parcelable` when there are already methods for reading and writing array lists of parcelables?
Well... the difference is simplicity - just add `implements Serializable` and optionally `private static final long serialVersionUID = SOME_CONSTANT` and you're DONE! That is the reason why I never use `Parcelable` - you can do all those things using `Serializable` with literally 2 lines of code - instead of many method inheritances and all that stuff...

Comment: The advantage of [Parcelable over Serializable](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable) is that it is **much** faster. If your list is big, the difference can be noticeable.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass Serializable objects via putExtra. ArrayList implements Serializable.

Comment: Huge help. Thank you. You'd think it'd be made more apparent.

Answer (score 6):

Mike dg is correct!

`putExtra()` and `getSerializable()` will store and retrieve an `ArrayList<>` of your custom objects, with no interface implementing required. Worked for me!

Comment: Sorry I was wrong .. your object has to implement Serializable.. but after that it works..