# Passing ArrayList with objects to new Activity?

Tags: android, object, arraylist, android-intent

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList from my first Activity to the next one. Basically, the first activity parses an XML file and creates an ArrayList with objects inside. What I want to do is send that ArrayList to my second activity and show some of the object data in a ListView.

I thought of doing this with an intent, but it looks like only primitive datatypes are usually passed through intents. Is this right?

If so, what would be a better solution to pass the data? Certainly Android must provide something to be able to do this kind of thing.

Any help/code examples are really appreciated..

Thanks

**EDIT:**

*I solved this by first creating and calling the intent, and only parsing the XML in the Activity that I called. This way I didn't need to pass the objects anymore. But for those interested, you can read about how to pass data through activities, [**here.**](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complex types may be passed by means of Parcelable. An example is in this question:

[Help with passing ArrayList and parcelable Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819238/help-with-passing-arraylist-and-parcelable-activity)

Answer (score 2):

I would do a toString on the array and pass it as an extra by doing a `intent.putExtra("label". array.toString());` and then just recover it in the new activity.

Comment: But will this work with complex objects as well, and is it performant?

Comment: If performance is your priority, I would not recommend it. I used it to pass a giant xml from one activity to another and it caused a major lag. Ended up fetching the data in the second activity instead. For smaller objects though, I feel like it should be okay.

Comment: `Intent.putExtra()` takes in a Bundle though, so you would need to do something more like this:

    `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray("arrayLabel",(String[])arrayList.toArray());
    intent.putExtra("extrasBundle",bundle);`

Then inside the Activity that will receive the ArrayList:

    `Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("extrasBundle");
    ArrayList list = Arrays.asList(bundle.getStringArray("arrayLabel"));`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a String List using `putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)` if it is strings.  Or, you could serialize List and then use `putExtra(String name, Serializable value)`.

If you don't want to/can't use the above, you could use a central util class with a static reference to the List.  Just set it in your first Activity and get it in the second.

Comment: I know about the putStringArrayListExtra() method, but I need this for more complex objects. And using static seems like a bad practice to me, looks really messy.

Comment: Using a static reference is of questionable repute, sure, but you can keep it very clean by using a dedicated class to get/set/store it.  I personally use it in an Android app with multiple pages and couldn't be happier.

Answer (score 1):

This could be totally bad practice and I wouldn't know any better, but you could declare the ArrayList as public and static. Then just access it with Activity.ArraylistName.

Comment: This is being recommended a lot, but it looks really messy though.

Comment: In my application I create the ArrayList in the same class as the objects, I store inside of it (in my case, a custom View). This makes it fairly easy to keep track of and stay organized.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scope of ArrayList at application level or you can do this using parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

I made this trick to send from first Activity to second.

The first activity

```
ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();  
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Second.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", mylist);
startActivity(intent);
```

The second activity

To retrieve

```
ArrayList<String> list =  getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```