# Sending ArrayList Objects between activitys

Tags: android, parsing, android-activity, arraylist

I am having a problem in trying to pass a ArrayList Object from Activity to Activity. Currently I am parsing a XML response using SAX Parser. The information I parse goes into a ArrayList. The information from the ArrayList is then used to populate a ListView using title as the name displayed on the listview slides.

What I want to be able to do is when I click on a item in the listview the assosiated information from that object will also be sent to the new activity and populate the fields which will display extra information.

I have tried creating a new adapter which links to the new XML layouts file but none of the data gets sent across. :(

I have looked into bundles but will that sent the whole arraylist or just the data that is associated with the listview I am using?

Any advice on approach's I can use to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending from From the activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(From.this, To.class);
myIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name",value);                             
 From.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and when receiving from To Activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> list=bundle.getStringArrayList("name");
```

Comment: Is value the name of the ArrayList ie: myArrayList and "name" being anything I want?

Comment: Yes it is anything and you have to retrieve your arraylist with this name from another activity

Comment: My ArrayList is of the type 'private ArrayList<Object> itemList;'. Is there a way of doing it as with string/char/int etc.. will throw errors.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835666/passing-arraylist-with-objects-to-new-activity

Answer (score 0):

U can send whole of ArrayList if it holds String values using this method `putStringArrayListExtra(name,value);` this has to be put into an Intent or bundle before starting the Activity using the Same intent...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Extra Content of the Intents as shown in this thread: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Also, you could inherit from the Application class and set some variables there to pass data along all the activities in your application.