# Passing ArrayList through broadcast intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, broadcast, parcelable

I followed the example at [Help with passing ArrayList and parcelable Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819238/help-with-passing-arraylist-and-parcelable-activity?rq=1) but for my case i'm trying to broadcast an intent from my Service class (Inside Asynctask) to Activity class like this.

```
ArrayList<Malware> addyExtras = new ArrayList <Malware>();

for (int i = 0; i < fetch.size(); i++) {
    addyExtras.add (fetch.get(i));
}
Intent d = new Intent();
d.setAction(COMPLETED_INTENT);
d.putExtra("CurrentProgress", "completed");
d.putParcelableArrayListExtra("MalwareArray", addyExtras);
sendBroadcast(d);
```

How i receive the broadcast intent

```
ArrayList<Malware> myList;
myList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("MalwareArray");
Log.d("onReceive", "got myList");

for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    Malware a = myList.get(i);
    Log.d("onReceive", "App Name:" + a.getApp());
    //tv1.setText(a.getName() + " is from " + a.getState());
}
```

It hits a nullpointerexception when trying to receive the intent

```
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.analyze.project.CompletedReceiver flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.analyze.project.AnalyzeActivity$1@41889670
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4513)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:974)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:741)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at com.analyze.project.AnalyzeActivity$1.onReceive(AnalyzeActivity.java:197)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
11-07 01:21:51.315: E/AndroidRuntime(18769):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: what is the line 197 of your file AnalyzeActivity?

Comment: It's `for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the log, AnalyzeActivity.java:197, you have a variable that is, unexpectedly, null on line 197.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("TAG", "onReceive1()");
    //setIntent(intent);

    ArrayList<Malware> myList;
    // use local var intent 
    myList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("MalwareArray");
    Log.d("onReceive", "got myList");

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        Malware a = myList.get(i);
        Log.d("onReceive", "App Name:" + a.getApp());
        //tv1.setText(a.getName() + " is from " + a.getState());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a inner broadcast receiver class that i'm using in `AnalyzeActivity` to receive the broadcast from my Service don't think i can do it this way?

Comment: I edited my answer to use the local broadcast receiver from the support package.  Give that a try.

Comment: It's working now but the problem with my code is im trying to also pass a drawable over too. Do i have to convert my drawable to bytes to pass it over?

Comment: yea,  if its not something your can pick up by 'getResources().getDrawable()' then covert that to bytes. it might be slow if its big tho

Comment: Anytime, calling setintent will set the activity's intent.  You may not want this in some cases if you use getIntent() a good deal elsewhere in your code. I changed my answer slightly to account for this.