# Passing data off ArrayList<Item> to other Activity in Android?

Tags: android, list, listview, android-intent, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with passing ArrayList and parcelable Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819238/help-with-passing-arraylist-and-parcelable-activity)

I have already tried to use `putExtra()` but to no avail.

When I use `putExtra()`, there were syntax error. and the only way (it seems) is to convert the whole data selected to string. But the problem is, I only need to display part of the data and not all of it. therefore I think that is not the way.

What I am trying to do is to send an `ArrayList` of data. The first Activity is where the program search the Array for the data and the second Activity is for displaying part of the data.

I need to send the data `onClick()` of the `ListView`. And I need the data to be in `ArrayList<Item>`.

Before anyone answers or comment on this question more please take a look at my reputation. So with that much reputation I think you know that I am new. Just take that into consideration before downvoting.

Comment: This has been covered at length in at least five other questions ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819238/help-with-passing-arraylist-and-parcelable-activity) is one such question, it links to others); start with Google... https://www.google.com/search?q=android+custom+arraylist+bundle

Comment: So why not make `Item` `Parcelable`?

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong I tried doing that but when i used parcelable, I cant display the result. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a class like this, which implements `Parcelable`:

```
public class CustomParcelableClass implements Parcelable {
    public String string;
    public int i;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(i);
        dest.writeString(string);
    }

            private Item(Parcel in) {
             string= in.readString();
            }
}
```

and you make an `Intent` like this:

```
ArrayList<CustomParcelableClass> myParcelableList = 
          new ArrayList<CustomParcelableClass>();
myParcelableList.add(...);
...
yourIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(LIST, myParcelableList);
```

where `LIST` is something like:

```
public static final String LIST = "LIST";
```

and in your second class, in a method like `onNewIntent(Intent i)`, retrieve your `ArrayList` through a line like

```
ArrayList<CustomParcelableClass> myParcelableList = 
        i.getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(LIST);
```

I do not know why this shouldn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried to implement what you told but somehow when the program wants to go to the other activity, the program will crash due to an error `Javabinder, !!!FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION!!!`. There should not be any memory issue right? After all the data passed is just a line of text.

Comment: @akemalFirdaus that has nothing to do with your initial problem. Google it and you'll find out.

Comment: Thank you, finally managed to do that.there was one method missing from your answer. I've already edited that.