# Is it possible to a List of Objects in putExtra

Tags: android, android-activity

I know putExtra can be used to pass objects/strings around between actives. But I am trying you put an `ArrayList` of objects like `ArrayList<Foo>` in `putExtra`

Is this possible?

Comment: No, but you can make the array parcelable, parcel it, and dump the parcel in putExtra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. You'll need to `serialize` your object into some kind of string representation. One possible string representation is JSON, and one of the easiest ways to serialize to/from JSON in android, if you ask me, is through `Google GSON`.

Also if you're just passing objects around then `Parcelable` was designed for this. It requires a little more effort to use than using Java's native serialization, but it's way faster (and I mean way, WAY faster).

From Docs :

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
 private int mData;

 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(mData);
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
     }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
     }
 };

 private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
     `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()` for passing Arraylist in intent.

Refer to [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.Integer%3E%29)

**EDIT :**
one more link : [Help with passing ArrayList and parcelable Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819238/help-with-passing-arraylist-and-parcelable-activity)

Comment: You need to make sure that the array is actually parcelable for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Only for very limited and particular types of "Foo". If i recall correctly Double and Long (or maybe it was Integer?) being those types. There might be a way to smuggle a more generic ArrayList through by encapsulating it in some Serializable Object, but I'm not sure about that.