# How to pass object list from one activity to another in android?

Tags: android

I had a object list in my activity and i want to pass that object list to another activity to generate a list view in that activity,is it possible?

For simple string values i had used the following code...

```
Intent intentprint=new Intent(OrdersScreen.this,PrintTemplate.class);
        String pbal=String.valueOf(Balance.getText());
        intentprint.putExtra("Branch", bname);
        intentprint.putExtra("Party", pname);
        intentprint.putExtra("Balance",pbal);
        intentprint.putExtra("Billvalue", bal);
        startActivity(intentprint);
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: A similar question is asked here, please take a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable/28673100#28673100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send arralist of objects as below

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("some_key", (ArrayList<TYPE>) list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve it

```
ArrayList<TYPE> list = (ArrayList<TYPE>)getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("some_key");
```

Comment: yeah but will suggest use ArrayList

Comment: By using the above i am getting an error like thisThe method putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<ProductsData>

Comment: Make sure your class implements Serializable

Comment: use arraylist instead of list

Comment: I had written complete funtionality based on List<Object>,now its difficult to change to Arraylist.Is there any option to convert List<Object> to ArrayLIst<Object>...

Comment: have you tried with List instead of arraylist look for this example http://aryo.lecture.ub.ac.id/android-passing-arraylist-of-object-within-an-intent/

Comment: I had converted my List into ArrayList but it was showing some error like this,The method putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<ProductsData>)

Comment: why there is extend parceble it should be like this intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("some_key", ArrayList<TYPE> list);

Comment: or just send as intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("some_key", list);

Comment: Based on your inputs i just pass ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> from one activity to another and get succeded for my requirement

Answer (score 1):

The similar question was already asked, please take a look at this: [Passing data through intent using Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable/28673100#28673100)

The only difference is the way of storing the object. The above mentioned method uses Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list",myStringArrayList);
```

to pass an arraylist to next activity.
See this for more complete details.
[Help with passing ArrayList and parcelable Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819238/help-with-passing-arraylist-and-parcelable-activity)